# What are the possibilities to call APIs in SSIS (Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services)?

Tags: json, api, rest, ssis, webhooks

I am looking for the different ways how within SSIS APIs can be called (e.g. getting data from a JSON file) or by calling APIs objects in SSIS can be accessed or configured (e.g. triggering an SSIS package).

Since I'm relatively new to SSIS and also have no hands-on experience with APIs in general, it's a bit hard to figure out the topic for me. What I have already found out through research is:

- You can call an API from your own code within a script task, but for that you need .NETor C# experience. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/432434/ssis-rest-api-authentication))
- There are third party tools like ZappySys, KingswaySoft or CozyRoc that provide so called Custom Tasks in SSIS, which are programmed by the third party themselves in .NET or C# (commercial).

Interfaces like APIs are one of the key requirements when it comes to data integration tools? It seems to me that SSIS is "lagging behind" here.

**Doesn't SSIS provide standardized tasks that allow the user to communicate with APIs like JSON, REST or Webhooks in a simple (no code) way?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say, SSIS is lagging behind in terms of integration functionality.  Most of features required in a modern platform are in Azure data factory.

Your research of using a script component or 3rd party component is your only option.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you do chose to go the script task method that you should consider going all the way to a console application using Core. SSIS is still limited to Framework and doesn't allow for Async programming which will dramatically slow down reading and processing complex Json.

Answer (score 0):

Using 3rd party tools like Zappysys fills this gap. It does exactly what you describe as your desire and it's easier to use than most of the built-in components of SSIS. There are sevreral predefined connectors to most common services like amazon